# Mostrar imagen guardada en base de datos

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

guardo mi imagen en la base de datos de sql server, pero no se como puedo mostrarla en otra vista en asp.net core.

la imagen que guardo, lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registro(UsuarioRegister user, List<IFormFile> Foto)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (Foto.Count == 1)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Foto)
                        {
                            if (item.Length > 0)
                            {
                                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                                    user.Foto = stream.ToArray();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                var usuario = new Usuario
                {

                    Foto = user.Foto
                };
                 _context.SaveChanges();
}

 public class UsuarioRegister
    {
        public byte[] Foto { get; set; }

    }
```

en la base de datos, la foto la guardo con el siguiente tipo de dato

```
foto varbinary(max) null
```

Como puedo mostrar esta foto guardada, en otra vista?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías retornar la imagen en base64.

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Foto);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
```

Y setear ese `imageSrc` en el `src` de tu imagen.